# Onlinebanking not working after last Tor-Update

Tags: error, update, website

Used Tor-Browser last weekend, new update was available and installed. Now my online-banking is not working anymore:( That's why I started to use Tor in the first place! Any suggestions what I can do? Is it possible to reset Tor w/o the new update? Not good with computers, so help should be described for a beginner and, to make matters worse, English is not my mother tongue. Thanks in advance :) Angelika